# Can Istio Rate Limit Virtual Service outside of mesh?

Tags: istio

I am trying to implement rate limiting for my existing applications that are not in the mesh.

Currently all that is setup is a ingress gateway, gateway and virtual service.

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: memquota
metadata:
  name: handler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotas:
  - name: requestcount.quota.istio-system
    maxAmount: 1
    validDuration: 1s
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: quota
metadata:
  name: requestcount
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  dimensions:
    source: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"
    destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.service | "unknown"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: handler.memquota
    instances:
    - requestcount.quota
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcount
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: istio-system
  services:
  - name: web-stage
    namespace: default

---
### Virtual Service
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-stage
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
  - "web-stage.host.com"
  gateways:
  - web-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: web-stage
```

With the quota set to 1 i should be able to have the service blocked easily but I am able to push thru any amount of rps.

I'm not sure where to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a problem with `rule` definition, as far as I know it has to be announced in the same namespace as `quota` resource, therefore `quota` has not being dispatched to the `memquota` adapter:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: handler.memquota
    instances:
    - requestcount.quota
```

For debugging purpose you can query logs from `istio-policy` pods by specifying [Mixer](https://istio.io/help/faq/mixer/) container:

`kubectl logs <istio-policy-Pod-name> -n istio-system -c mixer`

I encourage you to visit this [tutorial](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) for Rate Limits implementation in Istio mesh.